# Cannot get items using Vuex

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import User from './service/User'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
        users: [User]
   },

   getters : {
    getUsers(state) {
        return state.users;
    }
   },

   mutations: {
    addUser(state, user) {
        state.users.push(todo);
        console.log('Added')
    }

   },

   actions : {
       addUser({ commit }, user) {
           const result = User.users(user)
           commit('addUser', user)

       }

   }
})

export default store;
```

Hi all, this is my store.js i was about to get data from my backend using vuex. but it didn't work. i think i might be something doing wrong here.

Thank you in advance for your help. Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Hi! in your mutation "addUser" you use the variable "todo" but I can't see it declared in your code, also in your state you are adding User inside the array like you want to specify the type, I'm not completely sure that it's correct. Are you seeing 'Added' in the console?

Could you attach your Vue code? I think it would make easier to help you

Comment: //here is my Api.js
import axios from 'axios';

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: `http://localhost:3000`
    })
}

Comment: //here is my User.js or service
import Api from './Api'

export default {
    getUsers() {
        return Api().get('users')
    },
    addUser(user) {
        return Api().post('add_user', user)
    }
}

Comment: Im so sorry about that. Cos i am learning at tutorials. hehe kinda maniarism

Comment: //here is my user.js @ the backend
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema ({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;

Comment: i have a repo on github. https://github.com/lanceliamll/vuexpress 
sorry hehe.